# Python - how to get key value from dictionary inside a list with duplicate key names?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, key

I'm using Python 3.6.0 on Windows 10 64bit

I'm trying to get the url key value from line 604 of:
https://hastebin.com/iminawuguv.py

I was thinking maybe checking if 'format_id': '22', == '22' or something?

I tried:

```
url = url_info['formats'][0]['url']
```

but this only gets me the first key value on line 29.

Comment: Line 600 of your mega JSON response is `'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5'`

Comment: sorry about that I meant 604.

Comment: There is no way to get at it unless you know something more specific. Is it based on `format_id` that you want that particular URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
[d['url'] for d in url_info['formats'] if d['format_id'] == '22']
```

Your `url_info['formats']` is a list of dictionaries, and the one you want is the last element, so you may also do: `url_info['formats'][-1]['url']`

Comment: Why use a list comp. for a targeted value? List comp to me implicitly suggests there can be multiple matches.

Comment: It is used for searching a value here. List comp doesn't have to have multiple matches, it can be empty or just match one element.

Comment: I understand that, I just mean by its very nature it expects more than one match as possible. This is in terms of others reading the code with no prior knowledge. Nothing in the question suggests what the identifier is.